# How do I solve GlassFish error 'Glassfish server runtime requires full JDK instead of JRE' while configuring GlassFish server?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish-4

I am going through a strange problem which I dont know how to fix. 
I am trying to configure GlassFish 4.0 in my eclipse. When I click on GlassFish 4.0 from the server list and hit next, it throws an error stating:

> Glassfish server runtime requires full JDK instead of JRE

I already added `jdk1.8.0_73` in eclipse, so I selected that from the drop down. Once I select that it throws a new error stating:

> This server runtime requires JRE 1.7 or higher.

I have `jre1.8.0_66` also in the drop down, when I select that it again goes back to the previous error:

> Glassfish server runtime requires full JDK instead of JRE

The error goes back and forth whenever I select jdk or jre and I am clueless on how to proceed. Can anyone throw some light on what to do here?

Comment: I have gone thru the solutions provided for the similar issue in stackoverflow but it did not solve my problem..please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glassfish 4.0 does not support Java 8.

With you version of Glassfish, you need to install an select JDK 7.

If you want to use JDK8, try installing [Glassfish 4.1](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html) or newer, or replace it with a fully compatible fork called [Payara](http://www.payara.fish/).

Comment: Hi OndrejM,
Thanks for the advise, I just want to know the solution of the error im facing, please help. If the problem is because of Java 8, I installed JDK 1.7.0_80 and selected that during the Glassfish configuration, if i select that also, it is throwing the error **This server runtime requires JRE 1.7 or higher.** ..... Why it is not accepting jdk 7 also ...??

Comment: Thanks for the advise, it actually worked, I selected the wrong Jdk, after selecting 7 it worked ... Thanks a lot OndrejM!!

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish 4 does not support Java 8 yet.  than you need install  a Java 7 JDK for while.

There is a 4.0.1 release planned for later this year that will fix this.

Comment: Hi Poliana,
Thanks for the advise, I just want to know the solution of the error im facing, please help. If the problem is because of Java 8, I installed JDK 1.7.0_80 and selected that during the Glassfish configuration, if i select that also, it is throwing the error **This server runtime requires JRE 1.7 or higher.** ..... Why it is not accepting jdk 7 also ...??

Comment: Thanks for the advise, it actually worked, I selected the wrong Jdk, after selecting 7 it worked ... Thanks a lot Poliana !!

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish server runtime requires full JDK instead of JRE

1. Start eclipse
2. Go To windows ---> Preferances
3. Under javainstalled JRES hit Add button
4. Select ‘Standard VM’ Then Next
5. Set JREHome=” C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.XXXX”